# Is it safe to migrate our content databases to remote blob storage without downtime?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, rbs

We are currently moving the documents in our content databases into RBS.

There are many terabytes of data so we imagine this process will take a long time.

Just wondering, should I bring our site down during this process or is it safe for users to be using the site whilst this process is occurring? What would happen if a user wrote or accessed a document that was in the process of being moved? Would it just give an error or is there a risk of corruption of data?

Answer (score 0):

No need to bring your site down. Only set its content database as 'Readonly'

- Open CA > Application Management > Contetn database > click on its name > Set as readonly.